# Problem retrieving text from NativeScript TextField

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

#### Getting some unexpected behaviour with `TextField`

I have a function that's raised from `returnPress`. It takes the new `text` value and sets it as the value of a QR-Code message.

It all works fine until I pass a string like, **I'm on my way**. This will return **I\M-b\M^@\M^Ym on my way**. Which can not be passed to the QR-Code creator, as string data encoding fails.

It doesn't matter if I try to get the `text` directly from `args.object.text` or via `binding`.

If I take the `text` and set it to `Label` it renders as expected though.

Tried reproducing it in [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=52MfQ2) but I'm not seeing the issue there. So it must be something specific to my local project.

I've never seen **\M-b\M^@\M^Y** before.

- What is it?
- Can I undo it? or Stop it from happening?

Only tested on *iOS*, no idea if it will occur on *Android*.

Any insight is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: I've tested the Playground demo on my side with iPhone 8 / iOS 12 and everything works as expected

Comment: Are you testing by using the on-screen keyboard, or is this happening to you in a simulator and you're using your Mac's keyboard?

Comment: Native keyboard on device

Comment: The Flutter crew seem to have had a similar [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10218)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solved *( sort of )*

I haven't been able to uncover why some characters entered via user input are giving this particular encoding.

[Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10218) seems to have experienced a similar issue. But this stuff is all a bit beyond my knowledge ATM.

The good news is it doesn't seem to impact how the strings are rendered to the UI. So even when the text returned from the input event is `I\M-b\M^@\M^Ym on my`, The Label still displays `I'm on my` to the user.

The problem comes when it's time to store that encoded string in the QRCode. All discussions on how to store strings use `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`. I can't find it now, but I believe this is also the offical iOS recommendation. But with the odd encoding set, this in **no bueno**.

For now using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` does the trick *(Even with emoji)*.

So, if you see this output in your logs and you're just passing it over to a UI element there's probably no need for concern. But if encoding is an issue *(on iOS)* see [NSStringEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstringencoding?language=objc) for your options.

Comment: Found the link to the official recommended use of [NSISOLatin1StringEncoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIQRCodeGenerator). But again I'm having more success with `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code using VsCode and Android Emulator. Not seeing any issues.
Image updated with console output.
[image]

Comment: On `returnPress` what does `args.object.text` log?

Comment: Updated image with the console log statements output.